# Testing every number against a haskell program

Tags: haskell

So I'm trying to write a program that tests technically 1 - infinity. Basically i want to use take to tell the program to give me a list of the amount that take asks for. So just to clarify if I input take 5 I want to get back [1,2,3,4,5].

-For further clarification I am trying to understand how to recursively call a program over and over for the amt of times take says. I am trying to write a program that will give me a list of the next x even numbers starting at 1 where x = the number that take says.

Comment: You mean `take 5 [1,2..]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First off

Have a look at [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

## Analyse the problem

This is fairly straight forward, you need a function `evens :: Int -> [Int]`

## Most basic solution

Haskell has a list constructor that, in its most basic form, gives you a list of consecutive numbers: `[1..10]` will give you all the numbers from 1 to 10. Because Haskell is a lazy language, you do not need to give it an upper bound. I.e. `[1..]` will just return a list with all the numbers.

You can also run it with an interval, say 2 for even numbers: `[2,4..10]` will give you the evens from 2 to 10. So the function you need is indeed:

```
firstEvens :: Int -> [Int]
firstEvens n = [2,4..2*n]
```

This is also equivalent to

```
firstEvens' :: Int -> [Int]
firstEvens' n = take n [2,4..]
```

## Recursion

Recursively, you can run your function. Each step you just multiply by two.

```
firstEvens'' :: Int -> [Int]
firstEvens'' 0 = []
firstEvens'' n = 2*n : firstEvens' (n-1)
```